# Limit of a quotient without using L'Hopital rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How is the limit of :

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(ax)}{\sin(bx)}$$ found without using L'Hopital's rule. 
I tried substituting $\tan(ax)\cos(ax)$ for $\sin(ax)$, but did not get the answer.

Comment: your limit is a/b

Comment: As is, this question is a [problem statement question](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), which are discouraged.  Please [edit] the question to [improve it](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ).

Comment: Seems like this question plays out [two groups of users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077#252077):    'The "help vampires" who flood the site with bad/duplicate questions who only want their question answered and care nothing for the site.
The "repwhores" who answer everything they can (or can't).'  Don't try shaming me; I didn't write these words:  They are part of a post on meta.se.  I would personally add a category of spoon-feeders  ,  who insult the asker by assuming they're helpless; pity them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin(ax)}{\sin(bx)}=\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}\frac{bx}{\sin(bx)}\frac{a}{b}$$

Since $\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}\to1$ and $\frac{bx}{\sin(bx)}\to1$ our limit tends to $a/b$.